# Why “Get bored” is an accepted construction, but “get surprised” isn’t?

Tags: adjectives

Why “Get bored” is an accepted construction, but “get surprised” isn’t? Both are adjectives BUT get surprised" sounds a little unnatural.

the following sentences are from LONGMAN DICTIONARY

•   Julia soon got bored with lying on the beach.
•   I get bored if I’m at home on my own all day.
•   John was getting bored doing the same thing every day
•   I was surprised when I passed my driving test the first time.
•   I got a surprise when I passed my driving test the first time.

But I read [What is the difference between "get surprised" and "be surprised"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/44516/what-is-the-difference-between-get-surprised-and-be-surprised). I supposed the following sentence is unnatural.

•   I got surprised when I passed my driving test the first time.

Comment: Please include the source(s) for your sentences.

Comment: I edited it again.

Answer (score 2):

With "bored" there is a need (or desire) to distinguish between the dynamic "get bored" and the static "be bored".

But "surprise" is a short-term and always "dynamic", so there is no need for "get surprised" to specially indicate the dynamic sense.  And with no need for a form, it gets used less and becomes non-idiomatic.